# Client communication with Mule/ActiveMQ and C++ Stomp

Tags: c++, client, mule, activemq-classic, stomp

I have an external C++ STOMP client that sends a message to a queue

```
myqueue
```

and subscribes a topic

```
mytopic
```

A flow (Mule plugin in eclipse mars) receiving the message is configured, the message is modified and transferred for an echo response:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>

  <http:listener-config name="HTTP" host="localhost" port="8081"  doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

   <flow name="jmsFlow">

        <jms:inbound-endpoint  queue="myqueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS">

            <jms:transaction action="NONE"/>

        </jms:inbound-endpoint>

        <logger message="#[string: Logger1 Response: #[payload]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger1"/>

        <response>

            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>

        </response>

        <component class="org.mule.java.JavaClient" doc:name="Java"/>

    </flow>
```

The C++ STOMP client:

```
static BoostStomp*  stomp_client;
static string       notifications_topic = "mytopic";
static string       registration_queue = "myqueue";
static string       result("");
static int          number = 0;

bool subscription_callback(STOMP::Frame& _frame)
{
    number = _frame.body().v.size();
    result = _frame.body().c_str();
    return(true);
}

//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string  stomp_host = "localhost";
    int     stomp_port = 61613;

    char* msg = argv[0];
    int nmbr = 1;
    char* mymsg = new char[nmbr];
    strncpy(mymsg,msg,nmbr);
    mymsg[nmbr] = '\0';
    string msgstr = string(mymsg);
    try
    {
        // initiate a new BoostStomp client
        stomp_client = new BoostStomp(stomp_host, stomp_port);

        // start the client, (by connecting to the STOMP server)
        stomp_client->start();//(user, pass);

        // subscribe to a channel
        stomp_client->subscribe(notifications_topic, (STOMP::pfnOnStompMessage_t) &subscription_callback);

        // construct a headermap
        STOMP::hdrmap headers;
        string body = string("mymessage");

        // add an outgoing message to the queue
        stomp_client->send(registration_queue, headers, body);

        Sleep(10000);
        nmbr = number;
        strncpy(msg,result.c_str(),nmbr);
        msg[nmbr] = '\0';
        cout << "return message is " << result.c_str();
        result.clear();

        Sleep(10000);
        stomp_client->unsubscribe(notifications_topic);
        Sleep(1000);
        stomp_client->stop();
        delete stomp_client;
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        cerr << "Error in BoostStomp: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    cout << "Call of test works!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure about how to send the modified message to the topic

```
mytopic
```

instead of an echo reponse. Any suggestions?

Maybe, another option is to use a Java app that implements a STOMP-message sending:

```
StompConnection connection = new StompConnection();
connection.open("localhost", 61613);
connection.connect("","");

connection.send("/mytopic", msg.toString());
```

Receiving the message with

```
connection.subscribe("/mytopic", Subscribe.AckModeValues.CLIENT);
StompFrame frame = connection.receive();
System.out.println("JavaClient received message: " + frame.getBody());
connection.disconnect();
```

works, but the external STOMP client still does not receive it. The STOMP cout is:

```
[12:03:28: 00625D48] BoostStomp:starting...
[12:03:28: 00625D48] BoostStomp:STOMP: Connecting to [::1]:61613...
[12:03:28: 00625D48] BoostStomp:STOMP TCP connection to [::1]:61613 is active
[12:03:28: 00625D48] BoostStomp:Sending CONNECT frame...
[12:03:28: 0062E698] BoostStomp:Worker thread: starting...
[12:03:28: 0062E698] BoostStomp:server supports STOMP version 1.1
waiting for answer
[12:03:29: 0062E698] BoostStomp:Sending SUBSCRIBE frame...
[12:03:29: 0062E698] BoostStomp:Sent!
[12:03:29: 0062E698] BoostStomp:Sending SEND frame...
[12:03:29: 0062E698] BoostStomp:Sent!
```

Answer (score 0):

Below screenshot is the sample on how to send message to your subscriber using JMS(ActiveMQ) topic.

[Active MQ send topic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITo2h.png)

Comment: Thank you, but the subscribed mytopic of the client does not get the message: '    return message is =   '.  What about the host and ports? Does the setting match between ESB and client? The client uses boost.

Comment: <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" maxRedelivery="1"/>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP" host="localhost" port="8081"  doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ_Outbound" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
 <flow name="jmsFlow">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="myqueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>

Comment: <logger message="#[string: Logger1 Response: #[payload]]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger1"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="mytopic" connector-ref="Active_MQ_Outbound" doc:name="JMS Outbound"/>
 </flow>

Comment: INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:23,972 [[jms].jmsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:  Logger1 Response: mymessage
INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:23,993 [[jms].Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default outbound transformer: org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage
INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:23,993 [[jms].Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.service.DefaultTransportServiceDescriptor: Loading default response transformer: org.mule.transport.jms.transformers.ObjectToJMSMessage

Comment: WARN  2016-05-03 09:27:23,993 [[jms].Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.01] com.mulesoft.mule.transport.jms.EeJmsMessageDispatcher: Starting patched JmsMessageReceiver
INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:23,994 [[jms].Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.1799810639'. Object is: EeJmsMessageDispatcher
INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:23,994 [[jms].Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'Active_MQ_Outbound.dispatcher.1799810639'. Object is: EeJmsMessageDispatcher

Comment: INFO  2016-05-03 09:27:43,924 [[jms].jmsFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:  Logger1 Response: mymessage

Answer (score 0):

Hi @LeBro see sample below of sample source code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd">
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ_Outbound" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>
    <flow name="active-mq-testFlow">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="myqueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <set-payload value="#['Transformed Message : ' + payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint topic="mytopic" connector-ref="Active_MQ_Outbound" doc:name="JMS Outbound"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Try to access your local ActiveMQ using this url:
http://localhost:8161/

[image: I tried to create message queue using ActiveMQ admin to]

then try to run the mule application.

The mule app successfully consume the message then send it to topic.

[image: Sample topic created]

Comment: Hi @Arden Vallente. Got it so far, but the client is still not receiving the message. It can be seen on the local ActiveMQ.  I guess the issue is somewhere with the topics at different ports. ActiveMQ and Mule ESB with 61616 and Stomp client with 61613!?